# Error when use @NgController in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm new in Dart and AngularDart. So, i download some sample to study. But when i use @ngController, it makes error like this.

[image: Errors]

What can i do now? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NgController was deprecated about a year ago. Currently there is only a rootController everything else has to be a component. I don't know about Angular 2 yet.